# Inserting a Value from DateTime Picker causing errors

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

In a Windows Form on Visual Basic, I have a DateTime Picker for a user to select a time and date from.

I'm inserting this value via a parameterized query into an Access Database. However, as I'm running the form, I keep getting the error `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`.

If I remove the parameter from the Insert command, the field enters fine. But when I put it back in, it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub AcceptBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles AcceptBtn.Click

            Dim InsertTournamentQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Tournaments (SanctioningID, TournamentName, TournamentVenue, Game, Format, OrganizerID, PairingSystem, TournamentDateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            Dim LastRowSelect As String = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
            Dim LastRowID As Integer
            Dim DBconnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Master.mdb"

            Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(DBconnection)
                Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(InsertTournamentQuery, connection)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", SanctionID)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Trim(TrnNameTxt.Text))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Int(TrnVenueLst.SelectedValue))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", GameLst.SelectedValue)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToInt32(FormatLst.SelectedValue))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", OrganizerID)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToInt32(PairingLst.SelectedValue))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TrnDate.Value)

                    connection.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    cmd.CommandText = LastRowSelect
                    LastRowID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                    connection.Close()
                End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data type of the TrnDate variable?

Comment: TrnDate is a Form Control from a Date Picker. The .Value of it is the result of what the user picks.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the DateTime value and inserting in to database.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDateTime(TrnDate.Value.ToString))
```

Comment: Please, check all the data types in database are correctly matching to the values that you are inserting.

Comment: They are indeed correct. The column for the TournamentDate is set for Date/Time.

Comment: How can it will be Date or Time? Whats the actual DataType?

Comment: The Data Type in the Access Database for the column name "TournamentDateTime" is "Date/Time". http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Comment: Why would you take a datetime, convert it to string, and then convert it *back* to a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `#` before and after date value in the request

to make it clear please post a request example, use this command

```
Debug.Print "INSERT INTO Tournaments (SanctioningID, TournamentName, TournamentVenue, Game, Format, OrganizerID, PairingSystem, TournamentDateTime) VALUES (" _
        & SanctionID & ",'" & Trim(TrnNameTxt.Text) & "'," & Int(TrnVenueLst.SelectedValue) & ",'" & GameLst.SelectedValue & "'," & Convert.ToInt32(FormatLst.SelectedValue) _
        & "," & OrganizerID & "," & Convert.ToInt32(PairingLst.SelectedValue) & "," & TrnDate.Value & ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when you pass a `DateTime` value containing milliseconds as a parameter.  If you strip off the milliseconds from the time value, MS Access will accept the parameter value without a problem.  The easiest way that I know of to strip off the milliseconds is to make a method like this:

```
Public Function fixDateTimeForMsAccess(value As Date) As Date
    Return New Date(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, value.Hour, value.Minute, value.Second)
End Function
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", fixDateTimeForMsAccess(TrnDate.Value))
```